Iron PDF network print takes more time when compared to regular Adobe print
We are using Iron PDF to print PDF documents that's stored as varbinary in the database. We tried to compare the timing between printing from windows application using Iron PDF vs. printing an actual physical PDF file (same # of pages); the line Print() actually takes ~45 seconds to finish, while regular print from file using Adobe takes 3-5 seconds.
public static bool PrintPDF(byte[] fileContent)
{
    if (fileContent != null && fileContent.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new(fileContent);
            pdfDocument.Print();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
    return false;
}

Any suggestions on how to improve the printing speed?
Thanks

Have you read the documentation for IronPdf? Your code doesn't properly Dispose of the instance of PdfDocument. The easiest way to do this is to use a using statement. It's possible that your code is slow because of poor programming practices - both with the code that you've posted, as well as, the code that you haven't posted.

Previous question was closed because it focused more on locking the application than delay in print. We are trying to open a support ticket with Iron pdf. No issues in disposing . The line pdfDocument. Print takes 45 seconds even for one pdf document with one page. Appreciate your time Thanks

printing from adobe or from webview2 pdf preview control within application takes 6 seconds.  Thanks

I tested printing using the latest stable version of Iron PDF (2024.12.9), I noticed that Iron PDF uses a version of System.Text.JSON that's marked as vulnerable.  I also noticed that PdfDcoument.Print is (awaitable) Task<int>PdfDocument.Print... - the code you posted seems to be missing await. In my testing, printing a one page PDF document using Iron PDF (v2024.12.9) was five seconds faster than printing the same document from MS Edge (v131.0.2903.99).

we are using an older version. Trying to update it to latest and go from there. open support ticket if needed after that. Thanks

Tried same code with version 2024.12.9 - same delay takes 2 minutes 43 seconds for 5 page pdf with a network printer. From edge it takes 7-10 seconds. Thanks

Contacted tech support, and they suggested passing the DPI value to the print method. Seems to be faster now; it takes 7-12 seconds.
pdfDocument.Print(150);

Glad you found a solution. 150 seems kind of low - fax machines use a similar resolution. You may consider using a number from 300 - 600.

Yes 150 seems to be low, Using 300 after trying different numbers. Thanks

The following isn't an answer, but describes what I did for testing including the code that I used for testing printing using IronPDF (v.2024.12.9).

Create a new Windows Forms App (.NET 8)
Download/install NuGet package: IronPDF (v.2024.12.9)
It appears that this package uses a version of System.Text.JSON that is marked as vulnerable. If using Visual Studio, one can update this package. After the package is downloaded/installed, close NuGet package manager. Then in Solution Explorer, right-click your <project name> and select Manage NuGet Packages.... Click Installed tab. Scroll down to System.Text.Json and select it. It appears that version 6.0.11 isn't marked as vulnerable, so select that version and click Update.
Add a button to the form (name: buttonTest)

Then use the following code for testing:
Note: Ensure to add the async keyword to the Click event handler.
Form1.cs
private async void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //open a file dialog to prompt user to select a PDF file and print it
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        ofd.Filter = "PDF Document (*.pdf)|*.pdf";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            byte[] fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(fileContent))
            {
                int result = await pdfDocument.Print();

                Debug.WriteLine($"result: {result}");
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Debug.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {sw.Elapsed}");
        }
    }
}


Thanks.  I am assuming you tested this print with a network printer and not with print to pdf .

Tried same code with version 2024.12.9 - same delay takes 2 minutes 43 seconds for 5 page pdf with a network printer. Thanks
